# How to prevent RestHighLevelClient from blacklisting the Host?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-httpclient-5.x

I am using Elasticsearch client version 7.15.2

here is my `Pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>7.15.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.15.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
    <version>7.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```

we use Elasticsearch as service and other company provided us an IP/port to connect to it.

here is my configuration for `RestHighLevelClient`

```
@Bean
public RestHighLevelClient getElasticSearchClient() {
    String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes());
    Header[] headers = {
          new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json;charset=utf-8"),
          new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json"),
          new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*"),
          new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"),
          new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS,
                "X-Requested-With,X-Auth-Token,Content-Type, Content-Length, Authorization"),
          new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "basic " + encoding)};

    return new RestHighLevelClient(RestClient
          .builder(new HttpHost(elasticSearchIp, elasticSearchPort))
          .setHttpClientConfigCallback(configurer -> {
              configurer.setMaxConnTotal(maxConnection);
              configurer.setMaxConnPerRoute(Math.max(30, maxConnection / 10));
              configurer.setKeepAliveStrategy((httpResponse, httpContext) -> keepAlive * 60 * 1000);
              configurer.setDefaultIOReactorConfig(
                    IOReactorConfig.custom().setIoThreadCount(Math.min(ioThreadCount, 15)).build());
              return configurer;
          })
          .setRequestConfigCallback(configurer -> {
              configurer.setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout * 60 * 1000);
              configurer.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout * 60 * 1000);
              configurer.setConnectionRequestTimeout(0);
              configurer.setContentCompressionEnabled(true);
              return configurer;
          })
          .setCompressionEnabled(true)
          .setDefaultHeaders(headers));
}
```

we run heavy, numerous, automated queries against this Elasticsearch and sometimes I‌ see in the logs that the only Ip/port for this Elasticsearch gets blacklisted

```
[DEBUG]-2022/06/19 11:28:01-[http-nio-6060-exec-14]-RestClient.onFailure(514) - added [[host=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3500]] to blacklist
[DEBUG]-2022/06/19 11:28:01-[http-nio-6060-exec-7]-RestClient.onFailure(521) - updated [[host=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3500]] already in blacklist
```

1. How can I prevent this behavior(I mean blacklisting IP/port)?
2. Is my configuration convenient for heavy, numerous, automated queries?

Comment: I have the same issue with elastic rest client 7.13.2 
Have you found the solution and the cause of the error? please share it if you have fixed the problem.

Comment: @lia actually I couldn't find a solution, but as a work around I defined the scope of  the RestHighLevelClient as prototype, so each thread will receive a new resthighlevelclient.